# jQuery slide from right to left breaks in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

I want my content to slide from the right side of the window to the left side. The content div is centered with margin auto. Everything works as I want in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox the slide starts in the middle and go out to the left and then jump back to the middle.
Have searched but do not seem as if someone else is having this problem, something wrong with my CSS perhaps?

```
# JavaScript
$('[data-pjax-container]').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);  

#Css
#content { width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 30px; }
```

Edit, jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VBgkT/

Comment: can you recreate your problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ofc! http://jsfiddle.net/VBgkT/

Comment: Its Coffeescript, same as $('[data-pjax-container]'.click(function() { })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's something with the auto margins causing the issue.  You could calculate the margins in the script (sorry I don't know coffeescript syntax, so here is how I did it in javascript):

```
var x = $(window).width() - $("#content").width();

$("#content").css("margin-left", x/2);
$("#content").css("margin-right", x/2);

$('.click').click(function () {
    $('#content').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000)
    $('#content').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000)
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VBgkT/20/